# How to show the Contribution of Independent variables in terms of percentage in Multiple regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, r-squared, effect-size

I would like to show the independent variables (IV) contribution in percentage. For example,

Regression equation is `HeatFlux = 389 + 2.12 East + 5.32 South - 24.1 North`

```
R-Sq = 87.4%   R-Sq(adj) = 85.9%
```

Here, how would I say **East** is contributing `X%` and **South** is contributing `y%`? Is there any method to show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standardized coefficients (although beware that their interpretation is controversial). In SPSS you can choose to have this produced in the output. In R you can use the lm.beta() function in the 'QuantPsych' package: 
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/QuantPsyc/docs/lm.beta

The standardized coefficients can give you an indication of the relative contribution that the variable is making in predicting your IV. Higher values indicate higher contributions...These can then be translated into a percentage of contribution (if your standardized coefficients are B1, B2, B3, B4, then the percentage of contribution for B1 would be: B1/(B1+B2+B3+B4) - but this is not a typical thing to report and could be very misleading).

Comment: Thanks for this. Can we say this with R-squared? Like, with all these 3 IVs the R^2 is 85.9%. Let's say we are removing one of them and there will be a change in the R^2. Can we consider this change in terms of percentage? I seek experts' views on this.

Comment: You probably want to look at the coefficient of partial determination. This will give you the percentage change in the sum of squares of errors when for each IV...For instance, have a look at Applied Linear Statistical Models (2005 edition) by M.H. Kutner, C.J. Nachtsheim, J. Neter, and W. Li SEction 7.4 (p. 268ff)